# VB.NET - Edit XML and delete line if present

Tags: xml, vb.net, edit

i have this situation:

1- load xml

2- search if line (or word) is present

3- if present delete the entire line

4- save

For load and save xml ok, but 2 and 3 dunno...

XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Package xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/appx/manifest/foundation/windows10" xmlns:mp="http://schemas.microsoft.com/appx/2014/phone/manifest" xmlns:uap="http://schemas.microsoft.com/appx/manifest/uap/windows10" IgnorableNamespaces="uap mp build" xmlns:build="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/appx/2015/build">
  <Identity Name="Microsoft.MyApp" Publisher="CN=Microsoft Corporation, O=Microsoft Corporation, L=Redmond, S=Washington, C=US" Version="1.5.0.0" ProcessorArchitecture="x64" />
  <mp:appid Id1="1111" Id2="3333" />
</Package>
```

So, if `mp:appid`exist then delete the entire line

the result should be:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Package xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/appx/manifest/foundation/windows10" xmlns:mp="http://schemas.microsoft.com/appx/2014/phone/manifest" xmlns:uap="http://schemas.microsoft.com/appx/manifest/uap/windows10" IgnorableNamespaces="uap mp build" xmlns:build="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/appx/2015/build">
  <Identity Name="Microsoft.MyApp" Publisher="CN=Microsoft Corporation, O=Microsoft Corporation, L=Redmond, S=Washington, C=US" Version="1.5.0.0" ProcessorArchitecture="x64" />
</Package>
```

I think I have to use XML Namespaces...

thx all, sry for my bad eng...

Comment: Please post your attempted codes that include step 1-3 (and how it failed for step 2-3). Thanks

Comment: I would suggest to not use string based replace functionalities. There are some nice ways to edit xml and leave it valid. If your removed node wouldn't be closed in the same line, you would invalidate your xml.

Answer (score 0):

Try xml linq

```
Imports System.Xml
Imports System.Xml.Linq
Module Module1
    Const FILENAME As String = "c:\temp\test.xml"
    Sub Main()
        Dim doc As XDocument = XDocument.Load(FILENAME)

        Dim appid As XElement = doc.Descendants().Where(Function(x) CType(x.Name.LocalName, String) = "appid").FirstOrDefault()
        If Not appid Is Nothing Then
            appid.ReplaceWith(Nothing)
        End If
        doc.Save(FILENAME)
    End Sub

End Module
```